# How do the capacitance and charge values of a MOSFET datasheet affect the switching speed?

Tags: mosfet-driver, bootstrap

I am trying to figure out the proper values for my gate resistors (R1 and R2), bootstrap resistor (Rboot), and bootstrap capacitor (Cboot). My MOSFET driver IC is an [FAN7392](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/653385/FairchildSemiconductor/FAN7392/1). Here is my circuit:

[image: HIGH Side Bootstrap Capacitor Switching Circuit]

I have this [IRL40SC228](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRL40SC228-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462566bd0c701567ece08d03664) N-channel MOSFET and in the datasheet I came across the values of Qg, Qgs, Qgd, and Qsync, and the values of Ciss, Coss, and Crss.

I have read [some guides](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua887/slua887.pdf?ts=1661542228668&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) that say my gate capacitance is the one that affects switching speed and that gate capacitance is equal to Qg divided by Vg while other guides have said the values that affect switching speed are Ciss and Coss, and they don't even mention Qg and Vg.

I am trying to calculate these values, but I don't understand which values actually affect the switching speed of my MOSFET. I think I understand the math and RC constant behind calculating this, but I just don't know if I should use the Ciss and Coss values, or if I should use the Qg and Vg value to calculate these component values.

Which of these values should I be using to calculate the R1, R2, Cboot, and Rboot component values? Do the Qgs, Qgd, Qsync, and Crss values do anything that affects switching speed?

My MOSFETs will need to be able to switch 5000 times per second, or every 1/5000 = 0.0002 s.

Comment: All that capacitance and charge means 'slow.' To make a MOSFET fast, you need large values of *charging and discharging current*. That said, \$200\:\mu\text{s}\$ per cycle isn't all that hard with discrete power MOSFETs. So I suspect you will be fine. Say the rise/fall driver time is 1/10th the cycle time: \$20\:\mu\text{s}\$. Let's say you have to charge/discharge \$20\:\text{nF}\$. and the goal is to change the gate by 3 V each time. Then the current is \$\frac{20\:\text{nF}\,\cdot\, 3\:\text{V}}{20\:\mu\text{s}}=3\:\text{mA}\$. Kind of like that.